# Use code-second approach in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

How can I avoid database-first approach and avoid code-first approach with migrations instead of using code-second approach?

I want to design and develop database separate from the app, I want to map my model to my database (no `.edmx` file), using the Fluent API

Answer (score 0):

We have successfully implemented this approach in our software development process. Our approach involves maintaining EF Core classes on one hand, and a SQL Database Project on the other hand. For deployment purposes, we have a Custom Task that generates SQL scripts. These scripts are then packaged within an MSI setup using WiX. We opted for the Custom Task instead of the regular Visual Studio deployment method as it provides better control over database modifications and data migration.

Cons:
One drawback is that when making changes to the database, you need to make them in both the EF Core classes and the SQL Database project.

Pros:
However, the advantage is that you have complete control over the database deployment process.